# Errai - JSONException: Error > parsing JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: java, gwt, errai

When running my GWT application which use Errai-UI

I get this error:

> WARNING: Replacing Element type [INPUT] with type [BUTTON] Compositing
>   @Replace [data-field=username] element [] with
>   Component com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox [] Compositing @Replace [data-field=password]
>   element [] with Component
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox [] com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONException: Error
>   parsing JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I already added `RootPanel.get().clear()` during the `@PostConstruct` but still getting the error.

```
   @PostConstruct
   public void setup()
   {
       // Fix for Unexpected token JSONException being thrown
       RootPanel.get().clear();

       login.setText("Login");
       login.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                Window.alert("Logging in");
            }
       });
       RootPanel.get("rootPanel").add(this);
   }
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: could you show your template's html?

Comment: No problem, here: http://pastebin.com/VK2jgyPw

Comment: How do you declare your Home page widget? It would be good to see annotations and how the data fields are declared inside Home widget.

Comment: @Alexey are you saying that the error might be caused by the 'data-field' attribute?

Comment: yes I thought maybe there might be something wrong with declaration. in any case it is better to have more complete picture.

Comment: @Alexey I also got this error when I created a new Errai-ui project. Using a different CSS template already. It seems that this is caused by serialization error?

Comment: Could you post a longer exception excerpt, ideally if there is a stacktrace to see the exact location of code which throws the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may have a syntax error in your HTML5 template. I would verify that it can be validated as proper HTML5 without syntax errors. This would explain a template parsing error in the browser (that is what it looks like is happening here.)

Comment: I pasted my template here: http://validator.w3.org/check and got this result: Tentatively passed, 3 warning(s)

Comment: is this a bug in Errai or ? I already changed my CSS template and I am still getting this error. My page renders fine, I don't know why is this error keep on showing up every time

Comment: If you'd like more help, please contact us on the developer list errai-dev@lists.jboss.org - It would help if you have a sample project you could give us so that we can reproduce the issue. Thanks, sorry again you are having trouble.